# Migrate users from one Android app to another app in Google play

Tags: android, google-play

I have two apps with similar functionality, let's call them App A and App B. Now I want to remove App B and move all of those users into App A. Ideally I'd like to send out an update to App B that seamlessly transfers all of those users into App A. Can that be done and if not what are my other options?

Answer (score 3):

You can not do that. You could update App B and put a big banner saying that this version is not longer functional followed by a link to your App A.